# I have nested while loop php mysql. how to encode it to valid JSON

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

```
<?php

// header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
// header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

require_once ('connection.php');  

try {

   $selectCatagory = 'select Catagory_id, Catagory_name, Catagory_image from district_shop.catagory'; 
   $prepareCatagory = $conn -> prepare($selectCatagory);
   $prepareCatagory ->execute(array());

   while ($fetchCatagory = $prepareCatagory ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $Catagory = $fetchCatagory['Catagory_id'];
      $selectSubCatagory = 'select * from district_shop.subcatagory where Catagory_id= :Cat_id';
      $prepareSubCatagory = $conn -> prepare($selectSubCatagory);
      $prepareSubCatagory -> execute(array(
         'Cat_id' => $Catagory
      ));
      while ($fetchSubCatagory = $prepareSubCatagory -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         //print_r($fetchSubCatagory);
         echo json_encode($fetchSubCatagory);
         // It doesnot encoded to valid JSON     
      }
   }
} catch (PDOException $th) {

    $th-> errMessage();

}

?>
```

```
// The outpuut invalid JSON file is as  :- 
[{"Subcatogory_id":"1","Subcatagory_name":"Crasher Material","Subcatagory_description":"Crasher Material","Active_Subcatagory":"Active","Catagory_id":"1"},{"Subcatogory_id":"2","Subcatagory_name":"Plumbing Items","Subcatagory_description":"Plumbing Items","Active_Subcatagory":"Active","Catagory_id":"1"},{"Subcatogory_id":"3","Subcatagory_name":"Iron Material","Subcatagory_description":"Iron Material","Active_Subcatagory":"Active","Catagory_id":"1"},{"Subcatogory_id":"4","Subcatagory_name":"Cementing","Subcatagory_description":"Cement Material","Active_Subcatagory":"Active","Catagory_id":"1"},{"Subcatogory_id":"5","Subcatagory_name":"Marble & Tiles","Subcatagory_description":"Marble & Tiles","Active_Subcatagory":"Active","Catagory_id":"1"},{"Subcatogory_id":"6","Subcatagory_name":"Electric Material","Subcatagory_description":"Electric Material","Active_Subcatagory":"Active","Catagory_id":"1"}][{"Subcatogory_id":"7","Subcatagory_name":"Sweets ","Subcatagory_description":"Sweets ","Active_Subcatagory":"Active","Catagory_id":"2"},{"Subcatogory_id":"8","Subcatagory_name":"Salted(Namkeen)","Subcatagory_description":"Salted(Namkeen)","Active_Subcatagory":"Active","Catagory_id":"2"},{"Subcatogory_id":"9","Subcatagory_name":"Cold and Beverages","Subcatagory_description":"Cold and Beverages","Active_Subcatagory":"Active","Catagory_id":"2"},{"Subcatogory_id":"10","Subcatagory_name":"Food and Snacks","Subcatagory_description":"Food and Snacks","Active_Subcatagory":"Active","Catagory_id":"2"}]
```

Sir, I am unable to create its valid json as i have two tables in mySQL named catagory and subcatagory. 
so nested while loop is used to extract subcatagory by using catagory. The output is encoded in json but it was no a valid JSON.

Comment: What's your encoded JSON ?

Comment: Note that using SQL `join` statement will gives you extremely better performance rather than a nested loop. even you will lose your memory in a large volume of data by nested loop.

Comment: Would you use this and show us output ? `print_r($fetchSubCatagory);`

Comment: You say it's no valid JSON when doing: echo json_encode($fetchSubCatagory);.. What is the result then?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're echoing multiple JSONs without nesting them properly. Instead of this:

`[subcat1, subcat2, subcat3][subcat4, subcat5, subcat6]` *(invalid)*

Your output should look like be one of these

`[subcat1, subcat2, subcat3, subcat4, subcat5, subcat6]` *(valid flat array)*

`[[subcat1, subcat2, subcat3], [subcat4, subcat5, subcat6]]` *(valid nested arrays)*

---

In your code, you should harvest responses into an array, which you `echo json_encode()` in the end.

```
...

$output = [];
while ($fetchCatagory ...) {
  ...

  while ($fetchSubCatagory ...) {
    // for nested array
    $output[] = $fetchSubCatagory;

    // for flat array
    $output = array_merge($output, $fetchSubCatagory);
  }
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

That should do the trick :-)